# Standard equation for a saw-blade graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I have come across a problem where I need to generate values that when plotted look like the blade of a handheld saw:

[image]

I am sorry, I was not able to understand how to plot this (because I do not have the equation), so had to draw this by hand. It would be great if a standard graph/equation for this already exists or if someone can point me to how to get started on this.

What I tried?

$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} \times {min}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, \frac{x}{4000^{1.5}})$

The above equation gives me a plot that looks like:

[image]

So, I have one point of the saw blade, but, how to repeat it with decreasing height on y-axis?

Comment: You'll probably have to define it piecewise.  For example, you use one formula when $0\leq x\leq 1000$, another when $1000<x\leq 2000$, and so on.  Will that suit your needs?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a sawtooth function like arccot(tan(x)) or floor(x)-x+1 and applying the desired transformations. For instance you could apply an $x^2$ like function to get the curved shape, and add something like $\frac{1}{x}$ to get it to slope downward.

Comment: @TomKern, I am not able to put the idea as an equation...

Comment: @saulspatz, piecewise would work, but, how to control/update the parameters to obtain the gradual decay?

Comment: Draw each tooth separately and figure out a formula like the one you have.  To move the tooth $a$ units to the right, substitute $x-a$ for $x$.  To move the tooth $b$ units up, add $b$ to the formula.